# Where does solidity compiler saves the compiled binaries?

Tags: compilation, ethereum, solidity

I am able to compile the contract but I need to know where those compiled binaries are saved.. I'm using macOs BigSur. I'm really struggling with that.. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on tags of this question, I'm assuming that you're using the `solc` binary compiler without any framework (such as Hardhat, Brownie, etc).

By default, `solc` does not save the binaries. You can specify the output destination with the `-o` option.

```
# compiles `MyContract.sol` and saves the output to the `binaries` folder
solc --bin -o ./binaries/ ./MyContract.sol
```

---

From `solc --help`:

```
Output Options:
  -o [ --output-dir ] path
                       If given, creates one file per component and 
                       contract/file at the specified directory.
```